# how to use jquery variable in php to insert into database

Tags: php, jquery

hello in the following code variable checked_num contains the integer value like 1,2,.
now i want this value in database using php code using mysql insert query..
the jquery code i have is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   // function for counting check boxes
   $(document).ready(function (){ 
      $('.do').on('click',function(){
        var checked_num =$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
      });
   });
```

now i want that variable "checked_num" is accessed in php code so i can insert this variable value into database

Comment: you can do this by using ajax

Answer (score 0):

Have you readed the [jQuery ajax/post/get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ajax` to update your database.

**EG:**

```
$('.do').on('click',function(){
     var checked_num =$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;

     $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',          
      url: 'yourpage.php', //this page inserts your data in database
      data: {'checked_num': checked_num},
      success: function(response){
        //do whatever you want on success
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown){
        //handle ajax error
      }
    });
 });
```

You can also use `$.get()` or `$.post()` instead of `$.ajax()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery's `$.post()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/):

```js
$('.do').on('click',function(){
    var checked_num =$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;

    $.post('myPHPScript.php', { checked : checked_num }, function(data) {
       /* data is the response you receive from the server. */
    });
});
```

Here "checked" is the name of the post variable you're sending over. If you wanted to post a string named "myString" containing the text "Hello, world!", for example, you'd use `{ myString : "Hello, world!" }`. This is an object, meaning multiple variables can be sent over by separating each with a comma.

In PHP you'd then retrieve this using [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php):

```php
<?php
    $checked = $_POST['checked'];
?>
```

You'd probably want to encode this post data however before inserting it into your database.

As for how to insert the data into your database, check out [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Answer (score 0):

You are using javascript to set a flag if one or more of the HTML checkboxs in your form are checked.

So you already have a `<form>` on the page.

When you submit the form you can access that information directly using PHP

All you have to remember is that checkboxes are only submitted back to the server PHP code if they ARE checked. So all you need to do is test for their existance.

```
if ( array_key_exists( 'checkbox_name', $_POST ) ) {
    // this check box is checked
} else {
    // this checkbox is not checked
}
```